# Background image slows recyclerview performance

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, imageview

I have an application that contains a background image view and recycler view . When i scale fitxy to background image recycler view scroll slows down. When i remove bg image scale scroll performance is fast. But i cant use image view without scale fit xy  because even my images size same with screen size images is not fill whole screen . My images in the device storage . I read image as a bitmap and i set image component bitmap.

Edit : I forget an important point Android 5 or 5+ versions performance is better than Android 4. But Android 5 just better than 4 recycler view scroll still dont smooth.
 I tried Glide for image loading to imageview but result performance is still slow. Image loading code is :

```
   File f = new File(Constants.SETTINGS_MEDIA_LOCAL_FOLDER, 
   ApplicationManager.ShopSet.getMenuPageBackImage());
        Glide.with(ProductListActivity.this).load(Constants.FOLDERS_PREFIX + 
        f.getPath()).into(iv`enter code here`CategoryBg);
```

My layout xml is :

```
    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivProductListBg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
   />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llCategoryHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llBackButtonProductList"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvBackButtonProductList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Back"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivProductListLogo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llCartButtonProductList"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCartButtonProductList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="0,00"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llProductListHeader"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvProductListCategoryName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                    android:text="METE"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="28dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llProductListViewChoose"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llProductListSingleViewChoose"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivProductListSingleView"
                        android:layout_width="46dp"
                        android:layout_height="28dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:scaleType="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/singleviewbutton" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llProductListDoubleViewChoose"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivProductListDoubleView"
                        android:layout_width="46dp"
                        android:layout_height="28dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@drawable/doubleviewbutton" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llProductListHeader2"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvProductListCategoryInfo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                    android:text="METE"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="21dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llProductListHeader2"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_LanguageProductList"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/language" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llCategoryList"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerviewProductList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listviewProductList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:scrollingCache="false"></ListView>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

ivProductListBg is my bg image view. With same code if i remove ivProductListBg android:scaleType="fitXY" property everything is ok but when i add android:scaleType="fitXY" property recyclerview scroll is slowing down.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please, show us all the relevant code.

Comment: generating bitmap takes time, try to use image display library like Glide/Picasso

Comment: Please post some code to identify any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this can be an issue with the size of the image that you are using. Make sure it's not a very heavy file.

You can try compressing it or resizing it.

Comment: Compressing the image would add overhead while decompressing it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap)

> There are several libraries that follow best practices for loading images. You can use these libraries in your app to load images in the most optimized manner. We recommend the Glide library, which loads and displays images as quickly and smoothly as possible. Other popular image loading libraries include Picasso from Square and Fresco from Facebook. These libraries simplify most of the complex tasks associated with bitmaps and other types of images on Android.